# Unable to use variable substitution in docker-compose

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, fig

I use a mac to run docker and hence I am dependent on boot2docker or docker-machine . My application running in the container needs the docker host's ip.

I saw that the variable substitution feature of docker-compose is exactly what I need . When I try something like the below it works fine

```
extra_hosts:  
 - "somehost:162.242.195.82"
```

BUT when I try something like:

```
export DOCKER_HOST="64.88.225.66"



extra_hosts:  
      - "host:${DOCKER_HOST}"
```

I get :

```
$ docker-compose build --no-cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/code/compose/cli/main.py", line 54, in main
  File "/code/compose/cli/docopt_command.py", line 23, in sys_dispatch
  File "/code/compose/cli/docopt_command.py", line 26, in dispatch
  File "/code/compose/cli/main.py", line 169, in perform_command
  File "/code/compose/cli/command.py", line 53, in project_from_options
  File "/code/compose/cli/command.py", line 89, in get_project
  File "/code/compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in get_client
  File "/code/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 28, in docker_client
  File "/code/.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 58, in __init__
  File "/code/.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 362, in parse_host
docker.errors.DockerException: Bind address needs a port: 64.88.225.66
docker-compose returned -1
```

I'm not sure why it wants a port. It wasn't happy when I gave it a port number too.

So, how can I get my docker host ip to my container? It would be nice if i can pass commands like `boot2docker ip` or `docker-machine ip default` in the extra_hosts section or maybe if docker-compose could execute a script to get this value it would be great !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `DOCKER_HOST` is a variable used by `docker-compose` itself (https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#docker-host) and the format is wrong (it needs a `tcp://` scheme and a port I believe).

You'll have to choose a different variable to include it in `extra_hosts:`.

Otherwise you could just pass it in as an environment variable (`environment: [DOCKER_HOST=]`) and parse the ip address out of it in the container.

Comment: Ah that's right , thank you so much !

It would be nice if i could do something like 

extra_hosts:
-"some_host:`sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`"